# Can I perform a switch statement in AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, switch-case, switch

new SFMC user here. I'm just wondering if there's an equivalent of a javascript (or GTL) switch statement within AMPscript or if I'm restricted to using IF ELSE statements.

For example, If I take the example of GTL's switch, I would LOVE to do something like this in AMPscript:

```
  %%[
    var @value, @outcome
    set @value = RequestParameter('entered-value')

    switch 
      when @value =="Banana"
        set @outcome = "Yellow"
      when @value == "Apple" 
        set @outcome = "Red"
      when @value == "Pear"
        set @outcome = "Green"
    end switch
  ]%%
```

Otherwise, is it possible to combine GTL with AMPscript to achieve this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no case/switch syntax in AMPScript. You would need to use IF/ELSEIF/ENDIF statements to achieve the same result:

```
%%[
    var @value, @outcome
    set @value = RequestParameter('entered-value')


    IF @value == "Banana" THEN
        SET @outcome = "Yellow"
    ELSEIF @value == "Apple" THEN
        SET @outcome = "Red"
    ELSEIF @value == "Pear" THEN
        SET @outcome = "Green"
    ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: Thought so, thanks Macca.